I have a bug and dont know how to fix it
ProblemType: Bug
  DistroRelease: Ubuntu 22.04
  Package: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core 1:22.04.19 [origin: unknown]
  ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 5.15.0-107.117-generic 5.15.149
  Uname: Linux 5.15.0-107-generic x86_64
  ApportVersion: 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.5
  Architecture: amd64
  CasperMD5CheckResult: unknown
  CrashDB: ubuntu
  CrashReports:
   600:109:116:37:2024-06-01 21:52:42.417328142 -0600:2024-06-01 16:32:12.914270998 -0600:/var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.122.uploaded
   640:0:116:34569:2024-06-01 23:29:36.522152900 -0600:2024-06-01 23:29:37.522152900 -0600:/var/crash/_usr_bin_add-apt-repository.0.crash
   644:0:116:0:2024-06-01 21:49:43.722818411 -0600:2024-06-01 21:49:43.722818411 -0600:/var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.122.upload
   640:122:116:17606803:2024-06-02 22:21:30.263546943 -0600:2024-06-02 22:34:26.278599780 -0600:/var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.122.crash
   640:1000:116:135087:2024-06-02 00:23:26.533292770 -0600:2024-06-02 00:23:27.533292770 -0600:/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_webkit2gtk-4.0_WebKitWebProcess.1000.crash
  CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
  Date: Sun Jun  2 23:35:59 2024
  InstallationDate: Installed on 2022-04-26 (768 days ago)
  InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release amd64 (20160420.1)
  PackageArchitecture: all
  ProcEnviron:
   TERM=xterm-256color
   PATH=(custom, no user)
   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
   LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
   SHELL=/bin/bash
  SourcePackage: ubuntu-release-upgrader
  Symptom: release-upgrade
  UpgradeStatus: Upgraded to jammy on 2024-06-01 (1 days ago)
  VarLogDistupgradeXorgFixuplog:
   INFO:root:/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade running
   INFO:root:No xorg.conf, exiting

